# Spring Security JavaConfig: Configure required Channels (secure, insecure, any)

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

I'm trying to serve all static resources (css, javascript and images) through any channel but can't get it to work in combination with `.anyRequest().requiresInsecure()`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@PropertySource("classpath:security.properties")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${security.auth_urls}")
    private String[] authUrls;
    @Value("${security.secured_urls}")
    private String[] securedUrls;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(authUrls).authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.html")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout.html")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .requiresChannel()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**,/res/**").requires(ChannelDecisionManagerImpl.ANY_CHANNEL)
                .antMatchers(securedUrls).requiresSecure()
                .anyRequest().requiresInsecure();
    }

    // ...
}
```

When commenting out `.anyRequest.requiresInsecure()` it works.

I would like to serve specific pages with HTTPS, all other pages with HTTP and static resources with both.

Comment: Instead of `anyRequest` try `antMatchers("/**")`.

Comment: Oh, damned I used `"/resources/**,/res/**"` instead of `"/resources/**", "/res/**"`.

Comment: Doh, I missed that slip of the finger. Glad that it now works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
.antMatchers("/resources/**", "/res/**").requires(ChannelDecisionManagerImpl.ANY_CHANNEL)
```

instead of

```
.antMatchers("/resources/**,/res/**").requires(ChannelDecisionManagerImpl.ANY_CHANNEL)
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

In my app I need to have home urls unsecured (require http), and other to be secured (https only). I managed to do that by following the next order:

```
...
.and().requiresChannel().antMatchers(homeUrls).requiresInsecure()
.and().requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()
...
```

i.e. first goes rules, that permit (unsecure | both), then goes rules, that forbid (secure only).

HTH