# How to enable HTTPS only on Spring

Tags: spring, https

I found this:

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:form-login .../>
    <security:logout .../>

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/reports" access="ROLE_ADMIN" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/>
</security:http>
```

From my understanding we have to place this in web.xml, but we aren't using web.xml, we are using the java configuration. How can I achieve this? Is there anything I can perhaps add in application.properties?

Comment: This should point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800200/spring-security-javaconfig-configure-required-channels-secure-insecure-any

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing is a spring security file. Spring security can be configured either using an XML file (like the one you're showing) or through Java configuration (see here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html).

However your question is: can I enable HTTPS only.

You can also do that through other ways.
In Tomcat for example you can do that by configuring server.xml (http://www.itworld.com/article/2769041/development/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-always-require-https.html and https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html).

There are similar ways for other JavaEE servers.

You can also use a SecurityConstraint in your web.xml (or Java based Web config) so that it defines CONFIDENTIAL or INTEGRAL like in (XML fragment but you can do it via Java based config):

```
<user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
```